# Java selenium - If I use noncrypted password who can ascertain it? And is crypted password secure to send via selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, encryption, password-encryption

1)Hi, I would like to ask If I send noncrypted password for selenium, who can ascertain it?

2)And is secure if I send via selenium encrypted password like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfVyt.png) ? 
Or is it also risk? Is there any better security?

Thank you

Comment: 2nd option is good to use unless you upload your code somewhere and give access to anyone.

Comment: Ok, thank you. And if I don´t use it, who could see my password?

Comment: No one can see your password even if you don't use that but according to me as we have a facility to encrypt password, why don't we use it for better security.

Comment: one thing you can do is get your machine's serial number and use that as the key to encrypt/decrypt... that way if your code ever got out, no one could decrypt it but you.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog post about storing secrets:
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/test-automation-hiding-secrets-using-system-environment-nir-tal